# nginx reverse proxy with named location: how to override backend header?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, http-headers

I'm having a difficult time getting `add_header` to work when `try_files` is used to send requests to a named location which specifies a backend with `proxy_pass`.

Basically, I want to override `Content-Type` for a specific set of URIs, but don't want to use a `map` to set a variable for it (since I'd like the `types` and `mime.types` mechanism to continue working as is), nor to set an extension on the URIs and add more `types` declarations.

Here's a simplified version of my `nginx.conf`:

```
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  text/html;
    charset       utf-8;

    server {
        listen 80;

        location @backend {
            rewrite ^ /proxy$uri break;
            proxy_pass https://backend;
            proxy_intercept_errors on;

            aws_access_key ***;
            aws_secret_key ***;
            s3_bucket ***;
            chop_prefix /proxy;

            proxy_set_header Authorization $s3_auth_token;
            proxy_set_header x-amz-date $aws_date;
            proxy_hide_header Content-Type;
        }

        location / {
            try_files false @backend;
        }

        location ~ /(textfile|anothertextfile)$ {
            try_files false @backend;
            add_header Content-Type 'text/plain' always;
            # This has no effect either
            # default_type text/plain;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using [ngx_aws_auth](https://github.com/anomalizer/ngx_aws_auth) here, but I don't think that should matter.

The behavior I've seen with nginx 1.16.0 is that `Content-Type` is not returned at all; not for the `/textfile` location where I expect `text/plain`, nor for any other URL where I expect `text/html` because of the `default_type` at the `http` level. If I remove the `proxy_hide_header Content-Type` line then I simply get the backend's header, which is what I want to override.

I understand the frankly unintuitive behavior of `add_header` where headers aren't inherited from a higher level if `add_header` is specified at the current level, which I don't think is happening here, but I also tried moving all header directives to a standalone .conf file and including it everywhere, and I still get the same behavior.

I also tried using the [headers-more](https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module) module, with no difference.

What am I missing, Server Fault?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried switching the line `add_header Content-Type 'text/plain' always;` to `location @backend` block?

Comment: @PothiKalimuthu That would set 'text/plain' for all backend responses, which I don't want to do. Again, I want to serve 'text/html' as default, and 'text/plain' only for a few specific URIs. In both cases this needs to override the backend's Content-Type.

Comment: Okay. Got it. It was my misunderstanding, sorry. In that case, you could resolve the issue by having the exact replica of `location @backend` block into something like `location @custom_backend` with an extra line `add_header Content-Type 'text/plain' always;` in the custom_backend block. If this is confusing, please see my answer with the sample code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to use an additional named block to have a custom header for all the requests pass through it. The code in the original question didn't work because [add_header](https://nginx.org/r/add_header) is effective only on the last matched location block. If a request passes through multiple location blocks, it doesn't pick up `add_header` directive on the passed location blocks. Nginx only considers or looks for `add_header` in the last matched location block. In this case, the named location block is the last matched location block. I hope that clarifies why the original code didn't work as expected.

```
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  text/html;
    charset       utf-8;

    server {
        listen 80;

        location @backend {
            rewrite ^ /proxy$uri break;
            proxy_pass https://backend;
            proxy_intercept_errors on;

            aws_access_key ***;
            aws_secret_key ***;
            s3_bucket ***;
            chop_prefix /proxy;

            proxy_set_header Authorization $s3_auth_token;
            proxy_set_header x-amz-date $aws_date;
            proxy_hide_header Content-Type;
        }

        location @plain_backend {
            rewrite ^ /proxy$uri break;
            proxy_pass https://backend;
            proxy_intercept_errors on;

            aws_access_key ***;
            aws_secret_key ***;
            s3_bucket ***;
            chop_prefix /proxy;

            proxy_set_header Authorization $s3_auth_token;
            proxy_set_header x-amz-date $aws_date;
            proxy_hide_header Content-Type;

            add_header Content-Type 'text/plain' always;
        }

        location / {
            try_files false @backend;
        }

        location ~ /(textfile|anothertextfile)$ {
            try_files false @plain_backend;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that does indeed work. I was trying to avoid duplication, but that is easily remedied with `include`. It's just unintuitive how `add_header` behaves, and ultimately I reverted to using `map` to set a custom `Content-Type` variable, since there's seemingly no way to use this named location approach while retaining the `types`/`mime.types` functionality, as [this poor fella wanted as well](https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,215744,215744). It's surprising to me that something so basic (overriding backend headers) is so difficult to do with nginx. Thanks again!

Comment: Good to know that you switched to map. There are indeed multiple ways to solve an issue with Nginx. None of them are clean and easy. However, with the introduction of njs, the future of Nginx customization looks promising. When njs becomes a standard module, there will be a paradigm shift on everything about Nginx.

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't heard about njs. It sounds like Lua/OpenResty, and FWIW what I wanted to do can be accomplished with Lua, according to [this comment](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module/issues/1456#issuecomment-460452159), though I haven't tried it. I don't want to add that kind of extensibility/complexity when nginx should be capable of doing it OOB.